# PyQt5 - Unable to capture mousePressEvent in subclass

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm pretty new to PyQt and am having a problem setting up a signal/slot.

I have a `QTreeView` widget, whose parent is a `QTabWidget` which itself is inside a `QWidget`, whose nodes are a self-defined object, `Node`, which inherits from `QWidget`.

I want to enable clicking on nodes, to trigger - via a signal/slot - a change in model data in an accompanying `QTableView`.

Initializer and overridden `mousePressEvent()` in `Node` shown here:

```
class Node(QtWidgets.QWidget):                                               
     def __init__(self, name, parent=None):                                    
         super(Node, self).__init__(parent)                                     
         self._name = name                                                    
         self._children = []                                                    
         self._parent = parent                                                 

         if parent is not None:                                                
             parent.addChild(self)                                               

     trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)                                      

     def mousePressEvent(self, event):                                          
         event.accept()                                                          
         print("Node clicked!")
         self.trigger.emit() # this would have variables...
```

The mouse event is not being captured when clicking on the `Node` item in the tree.

I'm sure this is something to do with how I am setting up the widgets and/or the way `mousePressEvent()` works but I've been trying to fix this all day with no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going down the wrong path here. The correct way to access a user-defined `QTreeView` item is to use the `QModelIndex.internalPointer()` method and the `QAbstractItemView.clicked()` signal.

Eg.

```
self.selectionTree.clicked.connect(self.get_single_return_data)

# ...

def get_single_return_data(self, index):
    print("Signal triggered", index.internalPointer())
    p = index.internalPointer()
    # do something with p
```